# Difference between a ChannelReader<T> and IAsyncEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.threading.channels

Ill keep this one short

After reading the article ["Use streaming in ASP.NET Core SignalR"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-3.0) (first part, server to client streaming), what is the difference between a **ChannelReader[T]** and **IAsyncEnumerable[T]**?

Answer (score 1):

- Well, the trivial differences are that:

  - `ChannelReader<T>` is an `abstract class`.
  - `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is a [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) `interface`.
  - While anyone can subclass `ChannelReader<T>` - just like how anyone can implement `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` - *in practice* you'll only ever use the `internal` concrete subclasses of `ChannelReader<T>` returned from `Channel<T>.Reader`.
- While `ChannelReader<T>` does not implement `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, it does expose an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` *view of itself* via its `ReadAllAsync` method.
- It is the (reasoned) opinion of this author that there exists a difference in the *implied [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)* between the two:

  - With an `IEnumerable<T>` (including `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`) there's a *general expectation* that the `IEnumerable<T>` has a finite size (i.e. doing `foreach( var x in someEnumerable ) {}` *will* complete eventually instead of looping forever)...
  - ...while a `Channel<T>` (which is the source of a `ChannelReader<T>`) **might** never complete.
  - ...which means doing something like this (below) will cause problems if the `ChannelReader<T>` never completes:

    ```
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    await foreach( var x in myChannelReader.ReadAllAsync() ) list.Add( x );
    ```
  - I note [that in the linked page in ASP.NET Core's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-7.0) examples using `ChannelReader<T>`  the `ChannelWriter<T>.Complete()` method is called (eventually), which ensures things don't get-out-of-hand.

    - Which would be a problem in SignalR, because if you return only a `ChannelReader<T>` object, there's no way for the receiver of that `ChannelReader<T>` to get to the underlying `Channel<T>` or its sister `ChannelWriter<T>` object, so the `ChannelWriter<T>.Complete()` method *won't ever be called*.

      - ...which is a problem.
      - ...and this problem is mentioned in the documentation and so the documentation advises you to *instead* use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` *because* it can be cancelled/aborted by its consumer, whereas `ChannelReader<T>` *cannot*.

        > *Async iterator methods avoid problems common with Channels, such as not returning the ChannelReader early enough or exiting the method without completing the `ChannelWriter<T>`*
        > [..]
        > *Complete the `Channel` in a `finally` block*
      - ...so if you want to *safely* return a never-ending sequence of items (without using a `Channel<T>` as a source) then consider returning the sequence by representing it as a custom implemention of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.

---

In handy table form:

|  | `ChannelReader<T>` | `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Is normally implied (outside of SignalR) to have a finite size | No | Yes |
| Can *potentially* be infinitely sized (i.e. can iterate forever) | Yes | Yes |
| Can be safely completed (i.e. stopped) by SignalR | No | Yes |

---

Misc notes:

- Initially I thought that returning a `ChannelReader<T>` would always be safe because I expected `ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync(CancellationToken)` to call `ChannelWriter<T>.Complete()` whenever the `CancellationToken` was signalled, but as far as I can tell the token will only cancel the current read operation, it won't complete the `Channel<T>` itself.
- SignalR *does* support Completing `Channel<T>` objects, but only those that it creates itself (inside `internal class StreamTracker`), and not when you return a `ChannelReader<T>`.

Comment: Not sure about the *"general expectation that the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` has a finite size"*. Getting an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` out of a `ChannelReader<T>` is not uncommon, so whatever is the expectation for the one should also be the expectation for the other.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Right - I'm not saying it's _impossible_ (indeed, quite the opposite) - and I should have couched the explanation as being my opinion rather than hard-fact or something in the .NET specifications or even the guidelines - so I'm just basing it off my experience and from established convention.

Comment: You could also note that the mechanism that the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` has (and the `ChannelReader<T>` lacks) for communicating its completion, is the [`DisposeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable.disposeasync) method of the [`IAsyncEnumerator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1). The `DisposeAsync` is called automatically when an `await foreach` loop exits either normally or abnormally.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I thought about doing that, yes - but the problem is the (compiler-generated) `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` implemented by `ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync`'s return-type does not `Complete()` the writer when its `DisposeAsync` method is invoked and awaited. Grrr.

Comment: Yes, that happens because a `ChannelReader<T>` can be consumed by more that one workers. It wouldn't make sense for a channel to auto-[`Complete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelwriter-1.complete) because one of its consumers died unexpectedly because of an exception. The `ChannelReader<T>.ReadAllAsync` has no use for the `DisposeAsync` signal, so [it just ignores it](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v7.0.0/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.netcoreapp.cs#L18) (no `finally` in the iterator).